# CStringArray::GetAt(int index) returns a const. Why?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, visual-studio, mfc

I have a `CStringArray` and I would like to call `CString::MakeUpper()` on it to, you know, make it upper case.

I'm trying it like this:

```
mycstringarray.GetAt(0).MakeUpper();
```

where mycstringarray was declared like this:

```
CStringArray mycstringarray;
mycstringarray.SetSize(46);
mycstringarray.setAt(0,CString("StayClassySandiego"))
```

but Visual Studio complains that it cannot convert `this` pointer from `const CString` to `&`.

I get that cannot perform a non const function on a const, but why is `GetAt()` returning a const? More importantly, how can I perform this operation if the returning of const is indeed by design and not to be messed with?

Comment: _but why is GetAt() returning a const?_ Because someone decided for it to be this way.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for [GetAt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314338(v=vs.60).aspx) I can see that it returns `TCHAR` which is either `wchar_t` or `char`. How do you manage to call a function with dot from it?

Comment: GetAt returns a copy of the character at the defined position. So you cannot modify the string by using GetAt. That's why it is const. The return type TCHAR is probably a char or wchar_t which is a trivial type and doesn't have any member functions. You can only call MakeUpper() on the complete string.

Comment: I edited to show definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that's because how the interface for `CStringArray` (or more precisely `CObArray`) is defined. It returns a `const` reference to the underlying element. And `MakeUpper` can only be called on a non-`const` object since it directly maniuplates the object.

If you want to to change the value at an index position use the `[]` operator or the [`ElementAt()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/t8zddfxa(v=vs.100).aspx) method.

Comment: Ah, so is it true that GetAt() is only suitable for viewing the data, as opposed to modifying it which calls for GetData() ?

Comment: @user3064874 Like he says, or `[]` as in `mycstringarray[0].MakeUpper();`

Comment: Very well. That does solve my problem and change my approach.

Comment: I believe using `ElementAt` is a better approach. `GetData` is lower-level and returns a pointer (view) to the underlying raw array.

Comment: @SebastianStern: I noted you changed your answer after my comment, removing `GetData` and suggesting "`GetElement`" with a link that points to the `ElementAt` MSDN documentation. At this point, you may want to fix your answer replacing "`GetElement`" with `ElementAt` :)

Comment: @Mr.C64 Whoops, stupid me. Of course that's what I wanted to do in the first place. Thanks for the hint. :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN doc for `CStringArray::GetAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/088sck34.aspx#cobarray__getat), the prototype of this method is:

```
CString GetAt( INT_PTR nIndex ) const;
```

On the other hand, I spelunked inside `<afxcoll.h>` and (at least in VS2015) it contains this declaration:

```
const CString& GetAt(INT_PTR nIndex) const;
```

So, there's a mismatch between the MSDN doc and the actual code shipping with Visual Studio. Of course, what gets actually compiled is the latter, so let's focus on this.

`CStringArray::GetAt` returns a *const reference* to the original `CString`, and you cannot modify it due to `const`.

But, if you do want to *modify* in place an element stored in the array, you can use the **`ElementAt`** method, which is declared like this:

```
CString& ElementAt(INT_PTR nIndex);
```

In other words, this code should work:

```
yourStringArray.ElementAt(0).MakeUpper();
```

There's also an overload of `operator[]`, that just invokes `ElementAt` in its implementation. So `yourStringArray[0].MakeUpper();` should work, as well.

---

**P.S.** I'd like to add that, in modern C++ code, you may want to consider *standard* container classes, like `std::vector`, instead of these old MFC containers.

Note that `std::vector` works well with the `CString` class, so you can consider having a `vector<CString>` in your code.

Comment: You "spelunking" is much appreciated. I will definitely be looking into moving away from my old MFC containers. I am busy migrating someones Visual Studio 1998 code, so this will be added to the todo list.